# Datatable doesnt work in chrome

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, datatable

I'm having a problem with Datatables and I don't have a clue on how to fix it.

I use Datatables in a custom cms and everything works as it should on my Mac (Safari, Chrome, Firefox). Also with my colleagues everything works fine (Windows).

But we have a customer (and probably more than just one) where the Datatables doesn't show anything. I received a screenshot from the customer where only the  with the titles is visible. Datatables isn't showing anything, also not "No records found". This customer is having this problem in Google Chrome version 28.0.1500.95 on a Windows machine. When the customer opens Internet Explorer everything works just fine.

I can't reproduce the problem, so I'm hoping you guys can help me out.
Maybe this is a more common problem? Or is it possible the client has something on his pc, what causes Datatables to not work properly? The client has not disabled Javascript, cause then the cms shows a message and that message is not visible in the screenshot.

This is the JS I have for this table:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
      $('#applicationsTable').dataTable( {
        "aaSorting": [[4,"desc"]],
        "bPaginate": true,
        "iDisplayLength": 50,
        "bFilter": true,
        "oLanguage": {
          "oPaginate": {
            "sPrevious": "Vorige",
            "sNext": "Volgende",
          },
            "sSearch": "Zoeken:",
            "sInfo": "Toont _START_ t/m _END_ van de _TOTAL_ sollicitaties.",
            "sLengthMenu": "Toon _MENU_ sollicitaties"
        }
      } );
    });
```

Comment: Try to check for errors in the console tab of the developers toolbar

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer, but it might give you an idea how to start debugging. As JackPoint says, you obviously need to install Chrome, open the page there with Developer Tools running so that you can check the console log. I had the same symptoms in Chrome and was able to track down my bug so now Datatables are working. I think Chrome is very sensitive to errors and if there is a serious error embedded in your code, the whole fragile structure gets broken. In my case, I had to dig quite deep to find what was tripping Chrome up. I make an Ajax call to get the data for the datatable, then I populate a Knockout observableArray with that data. There is an HTML table on the page bound to this observableArray so it is automatically populated by Knockout after the Ajax returns the data. I can then call dataTable() on that table and it is decorated with sortable columns etc as usual. However, I needed to add a sort function to my observableArray in which I was attempting call String.toLowerCase, which Chrome thinks is undefined. Console alerted me to the error. I discovered the sort function was causing the behaviour. I first removed it and sure enough Datatables started working again. Then I went back and systematically checked the arguments object of my sort function (no problem) and finally realised I need to change String.toLowerCase to String.prototype.toLowerCase. Heaven knows why that's happening, but I hope this has given some ideas about how to approach debugging an obscure problem like this.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Popover attribute from datatable, it will work. If it is not added while creating table then once datatable binding is completed then remove the attribute pragmatically. This is work for me.